# Execution Error in BrowserStack after 50 minutes

Tags: browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

Appium script that is running in BrowserStack, is working fine for 50 minutes. The sequence is repeatedly calling for continuous execution. The session timeout for BrowserStack is set to 300 seconds. After 50 minutes, the execution always stops.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout issue you are facing could be due to two reasons.

1. SO-timeout
2. Idle-timeout

For more details,c refer to this documentation:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/references/timeouts